# Portal is down when a user tries to login

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, user-accounts, login

We had a user with login "DOMAIN\user" he left the organization long back. We have a new user with same name, infra team created the same login name for this second user "DOMAIN\user". Now whenever the new user tries to login the site is not responding, I have to recycle the App pool or reset the IIS. I have SharePoint 2013, but the said portal is still in windows authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an odd bug, but try running:

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "DOMAIN\User" -Web https://webUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "Domain\User" -IgnoreSid
```

Make sure the first line, `Get-SPUser`, points at a Site Collection where your *previous* user had access to (was added to the User Info List).

Once complete, try having your new user log in.

Comment: Works like a charm...Thank you. I do not know why i didn't think of Move-spuser...